# Nginx: Optimal map_hash_max_size and map_hash_bucket_size for 1M map?

Tags: nginx, performance, memory-usage

I have 1M static rewrite rules and using [this map configuration](https://serverfault.com/a/441517/69802). How to determine the optimal values for `map_hash_max_size` and `map_hash_bucket_size`? I want to optimize for memory consumption. The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html) is very minimal about this.

Somebody else [asked it on the Nginx forum](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,254572,254572#msg-254572), but without response.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much more simple to just check it?

Comment: Who cares? Are you trying to squeeze this into a Raspberry Pi or something? More to the point, why do you want to slow it down? 1M rewrite rules is going to be slow enough already. I don't think you should make it even slower.

Answer (score 5):

I made an analysis of source code for `server_names_hash_bucket_size` and `server_names_hash_max_size`, I guess it uses the same hash as the map.

Here comes generalized copy of my [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/786726/94256):

- The general recommendation would be to keep both values as small as possible.
- If nginx complains increase `max_size` first as long as it complains. If the number exceeds some big number (32769 for instance), increase `bucket_size` to multiple of default value on your platform as long as it complains. If it does not complain anymore, decrease `max_size` back as long as it does not complain. Now you have the best setup for your set of keys (each set of keys may need different setup).
- Bigger `max_size` means more memory consumed (once per worker or server, please comment if you know).
- Bigger `bucket_size` means more CPU cycles (for every key lookup) and more transfers from main memory to cache.
- `max_size` is not related to number of keys directly, if number of keys doubles, you may need to increase `max_size` 10 times or even more to avoid collisions. If you cannot avoid them, you have to increase `bucket_size`.
- `bucket_size` is said to be increased to the next power of two, from the source code I would judge it should be enough to make it multiple of default value, this should keep transfers to cache optimal.
- Size of `bucket_size` depends on length of your keys. Should the average key size be 32 bytes (with hash array overhead), increasing `bucket_size` to 512 bytes would mean, that it can accommodate 16 keys with colliding hash key. This is not something that you want, if collision happens [it searches linearly](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/c3aed0a23392a509f64b740064f5f6633e8c89d8/src/core/ngx_hash.c#L33). You want to have as less collisions as possible.
- If you have `max_size`  [less than 10000](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/c3aed0a23392a509f64b740064f5f6633e8c89d8/src/core/ngx_hash.c#L289) and small `bucket_size`, you can come across long loading time because nginx would try to find optimal hash size in a loop.
- If you have `max_size` bigger than 10000, there will be "only" 1000 loops performed before it would complain.

Comment: Great answer. I've written a detailed guide on tuning hashes [here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/tuning-nginx-maps-hashes), which basically expands your second point of increasing max hash size first while nginx complains, increasing bucket size when nginx complains *only about it*, then attempting to decrease the hash size for the most efficient setup.

Answer (score 2):

The nginx documentation on the hash and [bucket size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Key_statistics) is horribly vague. Are those numbers expressed in bytes? Entries?

I have a 128,592-byte [map file](https://gist.github.com/dandv/f6476574118d079b9063) with 1351 entries. The minimum values that worked for this case are:

```
map_hash_bucket_size 128;
map_hash_max_size 45948;
```

I don't know what the relationship between these numbers is. I arrived at them by increasing the bucket size to 128, then doing a binary search for the max size.